# Calculating hourly location points in Google Directions

Tags: javascript, google-directions-api

I'm trying to work out the most effective way to identify hourly location points on a roadtrip using the Google Directions API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

As an example - here's a route across New Zealand taking in some of the furthermost points on the main islands.

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Cape+Reinga+0484/East+Cape,+Gisborne/Haast+Pass,+West+Coast/Manapouri/Slope+Point/@-42.3931874,167.7648076,6.75z/

Google returns that the trip will be 2,934km & 42 hours long, which is useful...

...but what if I want to know where the car will be for lunch, or dinner?

If a car starts the journey at 8am, how can I return where it will be at 9am, 10am, 11am etc?

While I can work out that `2,934km / 42 hours = 69.857kph` that doesn't tell the full story as the route traverses all types of road conditions from 6 lane motorways to winding back roads to narrow mountain passes to a ferry trip between the two islands. So if I went down the track of calculating the car's location every 69.857km that won't be 100% accurate (but might be the best that can be done with the information at hand).

What is the most effective way to return a list of (reasonably accurate) hourly location points from a Google Directions route?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to figure out how to get information hourly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first method I've come up with is to do the following:

Cycle through each waypoint & pull out the duration value (seconds) & lat/long co-ordinates into an array:

```
                 "distance" : {
                    "text" : "5.0 km",
                    "value" : 5028
                 },
                 "duration" : {
                    "text" : "4 mins",
                    "value" : 217
                 },
                 "end_location" : {
                    "lat" : -41.331333,
                    "lng" : 173.2031939
                 },
```

I can then walk through the array & get a list of waypoint co-ordinates with the expected total time.

The only issue with this approach is that I can't calculate the exact position each hour, this issue is amplified when waypoints are a long time/ distance apart.

Any hoo - I'm going to start with this as a prototype.